# st_astext generate an invalid wkt in postgis

Tags: postgis, well-known-text

The query:

```
select st_astext(dn_geom), st_isvalid(dn_geom), st_area(dn_geom) from t$table
```

Generates an incorrect WKT from a geometry apparently valid:

> POLYGON((-2.96954161967213 41.4400844183428,-2.96950750532419
>   41.4400910442377,-2.96948715573845 41.4400950097163,-2.96947554344911 41.4400972585811,-2.96945962202308 41.4401003615618,-2.96944369975887 41.4401034653807,-2.96931177530061 41.4401290989185,-2.96917985084235 41.4401547332945,-2.96894920348446 41.4401995069094,-2.96894868296824 41.4401996074922,-2.96894798391747 41.4401997432791,-2.96875630570613 41.4402369522258,-2.96823832585221 41.4405354988708,-2.96817342393389 41.4405729601129,-2.96800387311005 41.4406706403037,**-2.96798005173981 41.4406-2.96677786044197 41.4413995549544**,-2.96640414237032 41.4416216636671,-2.96485357903934 41.4425433067817,-2.96146167994807 41.4445593909843,-2.96040869240291 41.445169481254,-2.95974632336177 41.4455532550955,-2.9590077862856 41.4459811278086,-2.95850920048038 41.4462699707237,-2.95870152158374 41.4461585534309,-2.96146164642046 41.4445593658386,-2.96365168949003 41.4432575782467,-2.96640407531509 41.4416215044109,-2.96727982247799 41.4411009580181,-2.96800385634624 41.4406706067761,-2.9682383266904 41.4405354980326,-2.96875630570613 41.4402369513876,-2.96894798475566 41.4401997424409,-2.96894920264627 41.4401995069094,-2.96917441014867 41.4401557500194,-2.96933617586039 41.4401243203952,-2.96944371736087 41.4401034477787,-2.96948797465044 41.4400948135798,-2.96950750448599 41.4400910408849,-2.96954161967213 41.4400844183428)) | t          | 1.01378542099019e-09 (1 row)

This is incorrect:
,-2.96798005173981 41.4406-2.96677786044197 41.4413995549544,

The WKT is missing a coma or ????

The tool i used to get the result of the query is "psql".

How can I repair those geometries? Or locate them at least

I want to load it from arcgis/oracle. They don't load all the geometries but no generate error. I think that fixing this problem i fix the other...

select dn_geom from table :

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

Comment: Probably GIGO -- The original geometry was loaded with Z and M values on that coordinste, but only on that one coordinate. To repair you should fix the load process.

Comment: For locating select the id of the feature as well.

Comment: Nah, this looks like a output formatting issue. What did you use to get the text? Are you 100% certain that the tool you used to get the result of the query did not "squeeze" the text into its output width?

Comment: Vince is right, seems that there is one coordinate with Z value. Using ST_Force_2D before ST_AsText should do the trick.

Comment: Write that as an answer.

Comment: Edit your original question, put the output of `SELECT dn_geom FROM thetable` there. Don't use `ST_AsBinary` that may strip higher dimensions. The hex in the comments seems ruined.

Comment: Assuming that's actually the full hex (can you paste it back into your terminal and get a geometry from it? I cannot) it points to internal corruption somewhere, since it's not a valid output `ERROR:  WKB structure does not match expected size!
LINE 1: select st_astext('0103000020A2100000010000002A0000003DD26409...
`

Comment: Please delete the comments with hex in them. As a rule, the OP (original poster) should not use comments at all -- Your job is to curate a question.

Comment: The hex have a space at the begin.  But it doesnt work in any case:
With space:
select st_astext(' 0103000020A21...
HINT:  " 0103000020A" <-- parse error at position 12 within geometry
whithout:
select st_astext('0103000020A21...
ERROR:  WKB structure does not match expected size!

Answer (score 3):

Seems that there is one coordinate with Z value. Using ST_Force_2D before ST_AsText should do the trick

SELECT ST_Astext(ST_Force_2D(dn_geom)) generates a correct polygon

POLYGON((-2.96954161967213 41.4400844183428,-2.96950750532419 41.4400910442377,-2.96948715573845 41.4400950097163,-2.96947554344911 41.4400972585811,-2.96945962202308 41.4401003615618,-2.96944369975887 41.4401034653807,-2.96931177530061 41.4401290989185,-2.96917985084235 41.4401547332945,-2.96894920348446 41.4401995069094,-2.96894868296824 41.4401996074922,-2.96894798391747 41.4401997432791,-2.96875630570613 41.4402369522258,-2.96823832585221 41.4405354988708,-2.96817342393389 41.4405729601129,-2.96800387311005 41.4406706403037,-2.96798005173981 41.4406848652324,-2.96797130941429 41.4406900871584,-2.96795622198768 41.4406990063421,-2.96677786044197 41.4413995549544,-2.96640414237032 41.44167903934 41.4425433067817,-2.96146167994807 41.4445593909843,-2.96040869240291 41.445169481254,-2.95974632336177 41.4455532550955,-2.9590077862856 41.4459811278086,-2.95850920048038 41.4462699707237,-2.95870152158374 41.4461585534309,-2.96146164642046 41.4445593658386,-2.96365168949003 41.4432575782467,-2.96640407531509 41.4416215044109,-2.96727982247799 41.4411009580181,-2.96800385634624 41.4406706067761,-2.9682383266904 41.4405354980326,-2.96875630570613 41.4402369513876,-2.96894798475566 41.4401997424409,-2.96894920264627 41.4401995069094,-2.96917441014867 41.4401557500194,-2.96933617586039 41.4401243203952,-2.96944371736087 41.4401034477787,-2.96948797465044 41.4400948135798,-2.96950750448599 41.4400910408849,-2.96954161967213 41.4400844183428))

Correction:
My fault. This isn't a correct geometry..

Comment: Mark the answer as accepted. :)